# How to clear a TextBox in a User Control in WPF C#?

Tags: wpf, controls

I have a user control that has a textbox in it, and i am using a clear button on my main form to clear information from the entire main window. i would like to clear the textbox in the user control once the clear button is clicked as well. i havent found an easy way to do this. i have tried referencing the control's name in c# followed by a "." however the name of the text box does not show up. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF declares controls in a `UserControl` as `private`. To make your `TextBox` `public` you declare it with a `FieldModifier` as in:

```
<TextBox x:FieldModifier="Public" />
```

where `x` is the xaml namespace `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`. However the recommended way of clearing a `TextBox` is to bind it to a property and then clear the property.

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to directly access controls within a UserControl from external classes or code. The simple mechanism would be to add a Clear() method to the UserControl which clears all relevant controls and information inside the UserControl.

Comment: ok i created a method, is there a way i can access it from the main window cs file?

Comment: The Clear() method should ideally go in the UserControl.xaml.cs file (as public), assuming that it is a UserControl that you created. Then you can easily clear the TextBox. If the UserControl is using DataBinding then you should make sure the bound element is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

The textbox could be bound to the DataContext of the UserControl. So a way of clearing it might be setting the property that is bound to the Text property of the TextBox to an empty string.